# How to register Redirect URL to webhook

Tags: c#, asp.net, webhooks, kaizala

Hi i've been strugling to register redirect url to Kaizal webhook (its chat app from microsoft like a whatsapp), I've create asp.net API Controller to register it in my Kaizala webhook. What i want to do is whenever there is a messege or Job created on  Kaizala Group, my redirect url will capture the data and save the data to my database. I think i already meet all the requirement from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/kaizala/connectors/webhookvalidaton, my Get method is already returning validationToken from Header. But it always return this error when i try to register my redirect url `"message": "Callback URL couldn't be validated. StatusCode = InternalServerError",`.

https://kaizala007.blog/2017/12/30/exploring-kaizala-webhooks/comment-page-1/#comment-3776
From this documentation he said i need support both get and post method, already add both but my post method still doesn't do anything just return statuscode.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace KaizalaTestApi.Controllers
{

    public class KaizalaCallbackController : ApiController
    {
        // GET: KaizalaCallback
        [HttpGet]
        public string Get()
        {
            string x = Request.Headers.GetValues("validationToken").FirstOrDefault().ToString();
            return x;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Post()
        {
            //string validationToken = Request.Headers.GetValues("validationToken").FirstOrDefault().ToString();
            //string data = new StreamReader(Request.Content).ReadToEnd();
            string str = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
    }
}
```

Why im getting that error ? do i need to do any specific thing in my post method to able make it works ?

Comment: Clarify if using asp.net web api or asp.net-core? The code in the question differs to what you said in the answer  about `asp net core 2.2 to make my callback url.`

Comment: yes i was using asp net before, but i change it to asp net core 2.2 after that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not the fact that you are returning `int` that it worked.

The first attempt failed because of an error when invoking

```
Request.Headers.GetValues("validationToken").FirstOrDefault().ToString();
```

Most likely a null reference exception, because you tried to access the token in the header, while linked documentation  states

> Kaizala will generate a validation token and send a GET request to your webhook **with a query parameter** “validationToken”.

***emphasis mine***

which was avoided in the updated used of

```
HttpContext.Request.Query["validationToken"]
```

I would suggest updating the syntax to

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get() {
    var validationToken = Request.Query["validationToken"];
    return Content(validationToken);
}
```

Of course you can refactor to add validation code for the expected query string parameter.

I suggest the above because there is no guarantee that the token will be a valid `int` based on the documentation. And even if it is, this approach would be more flexible if they ever do change away from using integers as tokens.

The requirements simply states

> Your service is supposed to return the validation token (received in request) in the response body as a plain-text

With that, only return exactly what was sent. Do not try to make any changes to it.

Comment: yeah i think i was wrong about get the validationToken, i get it from header at the first time, but then i change it to  query parameter, and yes the documentation doesn't say if i should return int in my get method but i keep gething error cant validate the token when im return as string or return action result  then i change it to int and it works

Comment: @TheodorusAgumGumilang does it fail with my suggested update if you do not cast to `int`?

Comment: hi its working now , i think the erorr i got before its because i try get the validationToken from header, but you need to change return to Content instead of Ok

Answer (score 0):

Already found how to make it works, it seem we need to return int in our get method that we get from query paramstring instead of string, i using asp net core 2.2 to make my callback url. Here take a look at my sample code to save in the database too

```
    [HttpGet]
    public int Get()
    {

        int validationToken = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Request.Query["validationToken"]);

        return validationToken;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void Post([FromBody]JObject rawBody)
    {

            using (TheoDBContext db = new TheoDBContext())
            {

                var jsonData = rawBody["data"];
                string name = rawBody["fromUserName"].ToString();
                string title = jsonData["title"].ToString();

                Kaizala newKaizala = new Kaizala();
                newKaizala.Name = name;
                newKaizala.Question = title;
                newKaizala.Answer = "yes";
                db.Kaizala.Add(newKaizala);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }




    }
```